# Convert text to XML using api

Tags: java, xml

I can't write correctly words.How  I can fix this?  I want something like this:

```
    <text><sentence>
    <word>a</word>
    <word>had</word>
    <word>lamb</word>
    <word>little</word>
    <word>Mary</word>
</sentence>
<sentence>
    <word>Aesop</word>
    <word>and</word>
    <word>called</word>
    <word>came</word>
    <word>for</word>
    <word>Peter</word>
    <word>the</word>
    <word>wolf</word>
</sentence>
<sentence>
    <word>Cinderella</word>
    <word>likes</word>
    <word>shoes</word>
</sentence>
```

but I have something like this:

```
<text>
    <sentence>
        <word>a</word>
        <word>had</word>
        <word>lamb</word>
        <word>little</word>
        <word>Mary</word>
    </sentence>
</text>
```

Example text

“ Mary had a little lamb .

Peter called for the wolf , and Aesop came . Cinderella likes shoes..”

And my class

My class

```
public class StaxWriteXmlTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws XMLStreamException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
            XMLStreamException {
        String[] word = initItems();

        // xml event writer with output stream
        // XMLOutputFactory xmlOutFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
        // OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\word.xml");
        // XMLEventWriter eventWriter = xmlOutFactory
        // .createXMLEventWriter(outputStream);
        XMLEventWriter eventWriter = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance()
                .createXMLEventWriter(System.out);

        XMLEventFactory eventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        XMLEvent end = createNewLine(eventFactory);
        XMLEvent tab = createTab(eventFactory);

        // Create start tag
        StartDocument startDocument = eventFactory.createStartDocument();
        EndDocument endDocument = eventFactory.createEndDocument();
        eventWriter.add(startDocument);

        // create config open tag
        eventWriter.add(end);
        StartElement configStartElement = eventFactory.createStartElement("",
                "", "text");
        eventWriter.add(configStartElement);
        eventWriter.add(end);

        eventWriter.add(tab);
        StartElement itemStartElement = eventFactory.createStartElement("", "",
                "sentence");
        eventWriter.add(itemStartElement);
        eventWriter.add(end);
        eventWriter.add(tab);

        // add words
        for (String words : word) {
            eventWriter.add(tab);
            createItemNode(eventFactory, eventWriter, "word", words);
            eventWriter.add(tab);
        }
        // eventWriter.add(tab);
        EndElement itemEndElement = eventFactory.createEndElement("", "",
                "sentence");
        eventWriter.add(itemEndElement);
        eventWriter.add(end);

        EndElement configEndElement = eventFactory.createEndElement("", "",
                "text");
        eventWriter.add(configEndElement);
        eventWriter.add(end);

        eventWriter.add(endDocument);
        eventWriter.flush();
        eventWriter.close();

    }

    public static void createItemNode(XMLEventFactory eventFactory,
            XMLEventWriter eventWriter, String elementName, String value)
            throws XMLStreamException {
        XMLEvent end = eventFactory.createDTD("\n");
        StartElement startElement = eventFactory.createStartElement("", "",
                elementName);
        eventWriter.add(startElement);
        Characters characters = eventFactory.createCharacters(value);
        eventWriter.add(characters);
        EndElement endElement = eventFactory.createEndElement("", "",
                elementName);
        eventWriter.add(endElement);
        eventWriter.add(end);
    }

    public static XMLEvent createTab(XMLEventFactory eventFactory) {
        return eventFactory.createDTD("\t");
    }

    public static XMLEvent createNewLine(XMLEventFactory eventFactory) {
        return eventFactory.createDTD("\n");
    }

    public static String[] initItems() {

        FileReader fr = null;

        try {
            fr = new FileReader("text.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader inputText = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String text = "", newText = "";
        String allTogether = "";
        String[] nexSplit = {};
        try {
            while ((text = inputText.readLine()) != null) {
                newText += text.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").replaceAll(" ,", ",")
                        .replaceAll(" \\.", ".").replaceAll("\\..", ".");

                allTogether = newText.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

            }

            String[] splitText = allTogether.split("[.]");

            for (int i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
                nexSplit = splitText[i].split("[ \t]");
                Arrays.sort(nexSplit, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
                return nexSplit;

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return nexSplit;

    }


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I can't write correctly words to xml using StAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943089/i-cant-write-correctly-words-to-xml-using-stax)

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.  You already asked this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943089/i-cant-write-correctly-words-to-xml-using-stax

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `initItems` which returns after the first sentence, due to the statement `return  nexSplit;` (in the inner loop). You have to collect the sorted words of a sentence into a List, and return that list. I repeat the lines that need to be changed in method initItems:

```
 public static List<String[]> initItems() {  // RETURN A LIST
     List<String[]> sents = new ArrayList<>();  // declare new List
     // ...
         for (int i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
              nexSplit = splitText[i].split("[ \t]");
              Arrays.sort(nexSplit, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
              sents.add( nexSplit );  // APPEND WORDS OF ANOTHER SENTENCE
         }

    return sents;  // RETURN THE LIST OF WORDS-OF-A-SENTENCE
}
```

Of course, the main program now has to deal with a `List<String[]>`.